# Golang1.8.1: TimeoutHandler doesn't affect multiplexer

Tags: go

I have this code which redirect http/s requests to login page, it works except TimeoutHandler has no effect, I mean the sessions don't timeout after 3 seconds:

```
func main(){

        mux := http.NewServeMux()
        rh := http.RedirectHandler("http://10.130.0.10:820/login", 307)
        mux.Handle("/", rh)
        tmux := http.TimeoutHandler(mux, time.Second*3, "Timeout!")
        go http.ListenAndServe("10.130.0.10:818", tmux)
        go http.ListenAndServeTLS("10.130.0.10:821", "server.pem", "server.key", tmux)
        var input string
        fmt.Scanln(&input)
        fmt.Println("done")
}
```

any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried seeing if the items timeout when you don't run ListenAndServe inside a goroutine? To test comment out ListenAndServeTLS, run ListenAndServe without launching a separate routine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I had to use ReadTimeout and WriteTimeout instead, here is a working example.

```
func main(){
        mux := http.NewServeMux()
        rh := http.RedirectHandler("http://10.103.0.10:8020/login", 307)
        mux.Handle("/", rh)
        s := &http.Server{
            Addr:       "10.103.0.10:818",
            Handler:        mux,
            ReadTimeout:    5 * time.Second,
            WriteTimeout:   5 * time.Second,
        }
        ss := &http.Server{
            Addr:       "10.103.0.10:821",
            Handler:        mux,
            ReadTimeout:    5 * time.Second,
            WriteTimeout:   5 * time.Second,
        }
        go s.ListenAndServe()
        go ss.ListenAndServeTLS("server.pem", "server.key")

        var input string
        fmt.Scanln(&input)
        fmt.Println("done")
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `http.TimeoutHandler` is not for making session expired after a certain time. Instead, it's used to limit execution time of a handler, i.e. if given time is elapsed, it will return `503 Service Unavailable` to HTTP client. Below is an example of such usage:

```
func handlerNoTimeout(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //This handler takes 1 second to finished, won't timeout
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    w.Write([]byte("Handler OK"))
}

func handlerTimeout(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //This handler takes 4 seconds to finished.
    //Before finished, it will timeout, 
    //503 response will be sent to client + given message (i.e. Timeout!)
    time.Sleep(4 * time.Second)
    w.Write([]byte("Handler timeout (never executed)"))
}

func main() {

    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    rh := http.RedirectHandler("http://10.130.0.10:820/login", 307)
    mux.Handle("/", rh)
    mux.HandleFunc("/timeout", handlerTimeout)
    mux.HandleFunc("/notimeout", handlerNoTimeout)
    tmux := http.TimeoutHandler(mux, time.Second*3, "Timeout!")
    go http.ListenAndServe(":818", tmux)
    go http.ListenAndServeTLS(":821", "server.pem", "server.key", tmux)
    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
    fmt.Println("done")
}
```

If your access `/timeout`, you will get `503` with timeout message, but if you access `/notimeout`, the http response will be `200 OK`.

A session is **a state stored** by the server, not **a processing steps/task/job** which may needs time to finish. A session won't expired unless you define a function/method/handler in background, watch the session creation time regularly, and if given time elapsed, mark it as expired.

In your code, it will timeout if redirect handler (i.e. login handler) needs more than 3 seconds.